# Transactional costs for shipping in % based on futures market price

Tags: futures, pricing, valuation, pricing-formulae

Real case: Imagine I want to move an oil from one terminal to another.

I have about 20 +/- tanker companies, but all of them have max capacity on their top deadweight (DWCC) vessel about `10'000'000 b(arrels)` **(1)**

As you may know, oil is traded in futures contracts with contract_size `x1000b`, but quotes are for `x1b`

Vessel companies have many options to evaluate their payment for transportation based on how much oil will be delivered by one ship for certain customer. **(2)**

One of formulas **(3)** I'm using calculate the the transaction cost % based on nearest future contracts price, for example:

$$
(FullPayment / (({\dfrac{DWCC}{contractsize}})) / contractprice ) * 100
$$

For example: 
$$
20000 / (({\dfrac{10'000'000}{1'000}}) / 74) *100 = 2.7%
$$
So the question is: `Is it okay? Can this formula been much more simplify then that?`

> **(1)**: Actually, there are much more companies, routes and vessel capacities, but the question isn't about it. It's also not about Incoterms/FOB/futures contract pricing, so I'm not interested in theory.

> **(2)**: In this certain example payment is fixed. Ship always goes by one-route from terminal A to terminal B in X days. Don't ask about any other options.

> **(3)**: The real formula is a bit more complicated than that, but basis of this exact situation is still the same. If you think it's a bit `simple` for QF just remember that in real case there are much more data and all this calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess it's all about Rubber Duck Problem Solving. Actually I was working on huge part of old legacy code/formula that misdirect me and I know that I'm probably missing something. But when I form the problem I easily solve it. Just calculate price of all `(DWCC x price)` and divide it by `transaction cost`

Thank you, QF